# handle uploading file via window prompt in Selenium, C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I get window dialog when try to open file (like that http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/services/its/servicessupport/web/sitebuilder2/faqs/files/upload_multiple/xp_file_browser.png ).
So I need set file path and click OK button. Selenium doesn't have  native functionality for it. I have found how it do on java:

```
StringSelection abc= new StringSelection("E:\\Study Materials\\Resume And Cv\\Sample 1_0.doc");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(abc, null);
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Does something like that support in C #?

Answer (score -1):

I found answer in following article http://cheryjose.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-to-interact-with-dialog-windows.html  - I sent path and Enter keypress.

Comment: Answers need to include more than just a link, please include a full description of how it works.